# format decimal number to specific exponential format in java

Tags: java, decimal, number-formatting, exponent

Number

- 13.33

o\p

0.1333 E+02

- 0.00023

o\p

0.23  E-03

How to use Decimal format to achieve the above output.
I want 0 number of digits before the decimal digits. And these numbers are range of double (not larger than that).

Comment: do you want exactly 0.13E+02 OR 1.33E+01 is fine for you?

Comment: I want my first significant number (non-zero) should start just after decimal

Comment: So your question is not duplicate. You should convey same to Scary Wombat.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310289/scary-wombat My question is not duplicate. I don't want to round or use big decimal

Comment: @ManthanTilva can you vote it to reopen?