# Fomat float and double into scientific notation in specific format given below

Tags: java, floating-point, double, decimal, exponential

I have already asked a question here and it was marked duplicate although it didn't solve my question and I tried to reopen but it got in vain. 
[Forcing BigDecimals to use scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18027047/forcing-bigdecimals-to-use-scientific-notation)

[format decimal number to specific exponential format in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58796212/format-decimal-number-to-specific-exponential-format-in-java?noredirect=1#comment103876403_58796212)

So before marking my question duplicate please see that it is related to my problem.

Question :

Given a float or double number op into specific format
eg : 13.33 = 0.1333 E+02
0.00023 = 0.23 E-03

The non zero digit of the number starts from just after the decimal.

How to use Decimal Format to achieve this output.

Comment: BTW if you want to notify someone you can do it by using @username

Comment: I don't want to round the figures. Yes I can use BigDecimal but I am unable to figure out how to force the decimal point in the beginning

Comment: @ScaryWombat I tried yesterday and written comment but When I was typing @ , your username was not appearing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want the non zero digit of the number starts from just after the decimal.

you can do

```
    BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal("13.33");
    DecimalFormat frmt = new DecimalFormat(".00E00");
    String formatted = "0" + frmt.format(x.doubleValue());
    System.out.println("result: " + formatted);
```

**results**

```
13.33
result: 0.13E02
0.00023
result: 0.23E-03
```